# How to select the last added row depending on ID - DataGridView/BindingSource

Tags: c#

I would like to select the newly added row.
This is OK when none of my columns have been sorted, but when they are, this just goes to last row.
My AppData has an ID column which I would like to use to select the latest row when I add a new row.
I have seen several similar questions online but none of the solutions worked.

```
  private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnNew.Enabled = false;
        btnEdit.Enabled = false;
        btnCancel.Enabled = true;
        btnSave.Enabled = true;
        dataGridView.Enabled = false;
        txtSearch.Enabled = false;
        try
        {
            panel1.Enabled = true;
            App.Phonebook.AddPhonebookRow(App.Phonebook.NewPhonebookRow());
            phonebookBindingSource.MoveLast();
            txtName.Focus();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            App.Phonebook.RejectChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you add a new Row, the `RowsAdded` event is raised. You can then select the new Row with `[DataGridView].Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;`. Note that this event is also raised when you first set the DGV's DataSource, of course (and, IIRC, it's also raised when you sort it).